# What argument to pass and how to find out its type?

Tags: rust

I started with the example for [EventLoop](https://carllerche.github.io/mio/mio/struct.EventLoop.html) from the mio webpage and added the main function:

```
extern crate mio;

use std::thread;
use mio::{EventLoop, Handler};

struct MyHandler;

impl Handler for MyHandler {
    type Timeout = ();
    type Message = u32;

    fn notify(&mut self, event_loop: &mut EventLoop<MyHandler>, msg: u32) {
        assert_eq!(msg, 123);
        event_loop.shutdown();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut event_loop = EventLoop::new().unwrap();
    let sender = event_loop.channel();

    // Send the notification from another thread
    thread::spawn(move || {
        let _ = sender.send(123);
    });

    let _ = event_loop.run(&mut MyHandler);
}
```

Then I had the idea to move the sending thread to a separate function "foo" and started to wonder what type is passed:

```
extern crate mio;

use std::thread;
use mio::{EventLoop, Handler};

struct MyHandler;

impl Handler for MyHandler {
    type Timeout = ();
    type Message = u32;

    fn notify(&mut self, event_loop: &mut EventLoop<MyHandler>, msg: u32) {
        assert_eq!(msg, 123);
        event_loop.shutdown();
    }
}

fn foo(s: &?) {
    let sender = s.clone();
    // Send the notification from another thread
    thread::spawn(move || {
        let _ = sender.send(123);
    });
}

fn main() {
    let mut event_loop = EventLoop::new().unwrap();
    let sender = event_loop.channel();

    foo(&sender);

    let _ = event_loop.run(&mut MyHandler);
}
```

So, I let the compiler tell me the type:

```
fn foo(s: &String) { ...
```

raises the error:

```
error: mismatched types:
expected `&collections::string::String`,
found `&mio::event_loop::Sender<_>`
```

Ok, nice but replacing `&String` by `&mio::event_loop::Sender<u32>` raises the error:

```
error: struct `Sender` is private
fn foo(s: &mio::event_loop::Sender<u32>) {
           ^
```

Hm, looks like a dead end, so I thought passing event_loop instead:

```
fn foo(s: &mio::event_loop::EventLoop<u32>) {
    let sender = s.channel().clone();
...
fn main() { ...
   foo(&event_loop); ...
```

but that raises the error:

```
 error: the trait `mio::handler::Handler` is not implemented for the type `u32` [E0277]
src/main.rs:18 fn foo(s: &mio::event_loop::EventLoop<u32>) {
```

which confuses me completely.

In e.g. C / C++ I would have just passed a pointer either to EventLop or Sender.

> What is Rust trying to tell me here? How to get it working in Rust?

Environment: rustc 1.0.0 (a59de37e9 2015-05-13) (built 2015-05-14), mio 0.3.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Sender` type is re-exported as `mio::Sender`. The compiler knows that the actual type is `mio::event_loop::Sender` and reports that. There's currently no way to automatically figure out what type you need in general, but you can look at the documentation of the [`EventLoop::channel`](https://carllerche.github.io/mio/mio/struct.EventLoop.html#method.channel) method and see that it returns a `Sender`. If you click on the `Sender` type in the documentation you will end up at the documentation of [`mio::Sender`](https://carllerche.github.io/mio/mio/struct.Sender.html)

Comment: Indeed, defining _foo_ as `fn foo(s: &mio::Sender<u32>) {...` and calling it `foo(&sender);` works. Thanks!

Comment: The compiler won't be perfect in guessing your types... I mean just try looking at what c++ outputs when you have iterators for a complex container... I've seen like a 500 character type before. It's helpful, but you still need to think about it a little. Another gotcha is when the Rust compiler tells you to use "core::" you should really be using "std::".